# Filtering java.util.Scanner input?

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I'm using a `java.util.Scanner`, and I want to filter out user input if it is out of range, for example only accept 0, 1, 2 or 3. Perhaps something like:

```
if !(sc.hasNextInt 0,1,2,3
```

I'm aware this isn't valid syntax, but I wanted to show what I was going for. How do I tell Java not to store user input that doesn't meet my criteria?

Answer (score 2):

This is something you have to implement yourself -- it's not something `Scanner` supports. A typical way is to have some sort of loop like this:

```
int input;
do {
    input = sc.nextInt();
} while (input < 0 || input > 3);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Test1
{
    public static void main(String [] args)
    {
        List<Integer> lst= new ArrayList<Integer>();
        //Take user input any number of times based on your condition.

        System.out.println("Please enter a number :");
        Scanner sc= new Scanner(System.in);
        int i= sc.nextInt();
        if(i==0 || i==1 || i==2 ||i==3)
        {
            lst.add(i);
        }
        //Go back
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
    public static void main(String[] args) throws AWTException, Exception {

            Scanner  sc = new Scanner(System.in);
            while(sc.hasNextInt())
            { int val= sc.nextInt();
                if(val==0||val==1 || val==2||val==3)
                {
                    // your code here

                }
               else
                {
                    System.out.println("wrong number, enter again");
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Kindly post reasons for downvoting so that I can improve my answers in the future.. :)

Comment: (PS: I am not the downvoter) Possible reason of downvote could be that you are calling sc.nextInt() multiple times in the if statement, which is incorrect. You should invoke sc.nextInt() once, and store it's return value in a variable, and use it for comparisions in the if statement.