# How To Limit User Input In Java

Tags: java, input

The amount of investment must be positive and can be any value.
The period of investment is in years so should be positive.
The annual rate of interest can be between 0.25% to 14%.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class InterestCalculator{

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO code application logic here

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        // Entering the interest rate
        System.out.print("Please Enter the annual interest rate between 0.25 to 10 : ");
        double annualInterestRate = input.nextDouble();

        double monthlyInterestRate = annualInterestRate / 1200;

        System.out.print("Enter number of years: ");
        int numberOfYears = input.nextInt();

        // Entering the amount earned
        System.out.print("Enter Amount: ");
        double Amountofinterest = input.nextDouble();

        // Calculating
        double moneyearned = Amountofinterest * monthlyInterestRate;

        // Displaying the results
        System.out.println("The money earned is $" +
        (int) (moneyearned * 100) / 100.0);
        int i;

        for (i = 1; i <= numberOfYears * 12; i++) {
            double Balance = Amountofinterest + moneyearned;
            Amountofinterest = Balance;
            monthlyInterestRate = moneyearned + 0.01;
            System.out.println(i + "\t\t" + Amountofinterest
                    + "\t\t" + monthlyInterestRate + "\t\t" + Balance);

        }

    }
}
```

I have made the basic program but, I don't know how to add restrictions.

Comment: Ok.. What about `if` statement?

Comment: See also: [How to filter Scanner input](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20834913/filtering-java-util-scanner-input)

Answer (score 0):

You can use loops that repeatedly ask for input until it's valid:

```
double annualInterestRate = 0;
while (annualInterestRate < 0.25 || annualInterestRate > 10){
    System.out.print("Please Enter the annual interest rate between 0.25 to 10 : ");
    annualInterestRate = input.nextDouble();
    if (annualInterestRate < 0.25 || annualInterestRate > 10){
        System.out.println("Please enter a value between 0.25 and 10");
    }
}
//if you reach this point, input is valid because it is neither <0.25 or >10
```

You can do this for all values that need to meet certain criteria. Just make sure you initialize the variable *before* the loop and set it as an invalid value, otherwise the loop won't run.

Other variables:

```
int numberOfYears = -1; //or 0 is you don't allow 0 years
while (numberOfYears < 0){ //or <= 0 if you don't allow 0 years
    System.out.print("Enter number of years: ");
    numberOfYears = input.nextInt();
}
double Amountofinterest = -1; //or 0
while (Amountofinterest < 0){ //or <= 0
    System.out.print("Enter Amount: ");
    Amountofinterest = input.nextDouble();
}
```

Comment: You are defining a new `double annualInterestRate` in your while. You should remove the `double`.

Comment: Good eye. My bad. Edited it

Comment: thanks..this worked perfectly for the annual rate restriction...can you please tell me for the other 2 restrictions...thank you very much for the help and the quick reply.

Answer (score 0):

Are you talking about this :

```
while(input.nextDouble()<0){
         System.out.println("Please enter positive investment");

     }
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok you could then use a while loop like this:

```
    int numberOfYears = -1;
    System.out.print( "Enter number of years: ");
    while(numberOfYears < 0){ 
    numberOfYears = input.nextInt();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd like to offer a more elegant way of getting data via CLI, where the risk of exception or any other input hazard is minimised.

I've written this function and think it may well cover the Integer, Double and String objects, but you may continue expanding it further:

```
public Object securedInput(String intro, String type, int maxLength)
{
    //Apply Scanner
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    
    //Show intro
    if(intro != null)
        System.out.print(intro+" ");
    
    //Get user's input
    String  inStr = input.next(); //always get a string
    
    //Enforce length
    if((maxLength>0)&&(inStr.length() > maxLength))
        inStr = inStr.substring(0, maxLength);
    
    String  result;
    
    if(inStr == null || inStr.length() < 1)
        return null;
    
    switch (type)
    {
            case "int":
                result = inStr.replaceAll("[^0-9]", "");
                if(result.length() < 1 || result.length() < inStr.length())
                    return null;
                else
                   return Integer.parseInt(result);
            case "double":
                result = inStr.replaceAll("[^0-9.]", "");
                if(result.length() < 1 || result.length() < inStr.length())
                    return null;
                else
                    return Double.parseDouble(result);
                //break;
            case "string":
                result = inStr.replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z .-]", "");
                if(result.length() < 1 || result.length() < inStr.length())
                    return null;
                else
                    return result;
            default:
                return null;
    }
           
}
```

Here,as you can see I first take the input as String, then clean it according to my need, and then try to convert it without the risk of getting any exception.
And if something is wrong you simply get a null.

This can be used like this:

```
    Integer i = (Integer)securedInput("Enter an integer:","int", 3);
    Double  d = (Double)securedInput("Enter a double","double",4);
    String  s = (String)securedInput("Enter a string","string",2);
```

You can add further arguments, such as range, and forbidden characters and even output errors according to the problem.

Hope this had helped.